# Scala: how to replace deprecated ObservableMap

Tags: scala, deprecated

in a scalafx application I am using (want to use) ObservableMap so that changes to the map can be reacted upon in the GUI.

The Scala API says

> (Since version 2.11.0) observables are deprecated because scripting is deprecated

which is not very helpful, since I am not doing scripting (never heard about Scala scripting anyway) and I still think it is a useful concept.

What is the suggested replacement procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have issues with imports. You want to use

```
scalafx.collections.ObservableMap
```

and not

```
scala.collection.mutable.ObservableMap
```